# how to configure jmx exporter in tomcat for prometheus

Tags: jmx, grafana, prometheus, exporter

I am trying to configure jmx monitor for monitor my java metrics. but facing some issue which is described below.

My current process:

I set below parameters in my catalina.sh file.

```
Prometheus_JMX_OPTS="-javaagent:/home/centos/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.11.0.jar=7777:/home/centos/config.yml"

JMX_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=3000 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=3000 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"

JAVA_OPTS="-Xms${JVM_MINIMUM_MEMORY} -Xmx${JVM_MAXIMUM_MEMORY} ${JAVA_OPTS} ${OPC_JVM_ARGS} ${JVM_REQUIRED_ARGS} ${DISABLE_NOTIFICATIONS} ${JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS} ${JVM_EXTRA_ARGS} ${JIRA_HOME_MINUSD} ${JMX_OPTS} ${Prometheus_JMX_OPTS}"
```

I download the `jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.11.0.jar` file in `/home/centos` path.

Create a config file with below content.

```
startDelaySeconds: 0
ssl: false
lowercaseOutputName: false
lowercaseOutputLabelNames: false
```

Open 7777 port from Security groups.

Now when I trying to access http://localhost:7777/metrics then it is showing unable to reach now.

Anyone can help me into this, I am stuck here . ☺

Comment: Did you ever get this working, can you share if you did?